# Defensive attribution vs Self-serving bias

Tags: social-psychology, bias, attribution

What is the difference between "Defensive attribution" and the "self-serving-bias"?

Both seem to involve a practice where one would attribute our failures to circumstances and our successes to ourselves...

Thanks!

Comment: What source are you basing your current interpretations on? Could you please include a reference/link in your question?